# In Rails, problems reading a point type from MySQL with mysql2 gem

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm working in a refactor from a legacy system and I'm having trouble with the "point" data type.

Inside Sequel Pro I can see the column "location" value as `POINT(-22.81507676827597 -47.07767857976228)`

But when I query it from the database

```
Mysql2::Client.new(
          host: ENV.fetch('LEGACY_DATABASE_HOST'),
          username: ENV.fetch('LEGACY_DATABASE_USERNAME'),
          password: ENV.fetch('LEGACY_DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
          database: ENV.fetch('LEGACY_DATABASE_NAME')
        ).query("SELECT * FROM local").first('location')
```

I get a weird result like "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x84y\xFF\xDE\xA8\xD06\xC0\xE0\xD6'_\xF1\x89G\xC0", if I try to save it right away, it becomes a 0.

How is the proper way to deal with point data type in mysql with rails?

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend that you use the [activerecord-postgis-adapter](https://github.com/rgeo/activerecord-postgis-adapter) gem, makes all this very simple.  Although if you're set on doing it yourself, dig into that gem and see how they do the `point` stuff.